# Creating a cluster-wide readonly user in Kubernetes using RBAC for Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, certificate, grafana, rbac

I'm trying to provision a user so that Grafana is able to monitor my cluster's resources. I've followed the Bitnami guide [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/). And implemented the steps as an Ansible playbook found [here](https://github.com/zimmertr/Kubernetes-Manifests/blob/master/Grafana/provision.yml).

[Here](https://github.com/zimmertr/Kubernetes-Manifests/blob/master/Grafana/manifests/cr_prometheus.yml.j2) is the ClusterRole that the user uses and [here](https://github.com/zimmertr/Kubernetes-Manifests/blob/master/Grafana/manifests/crb_prometheus.yml.j2) is how it is bound to the user.

However, despite this, Grafana throws [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sedv.png) error when I configure it with the generated certificates.

Furthermore, if I attempt to run any command with the user context, it says I'm unauthorized.

```
$> kubectl --context=grafana-prometheus-scraper get pods -n grafana
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is how your ServiceAccount, [ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) should look like.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: grafana-prometheus-scraper

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: grafana-prometheus-scraper
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - secrets
      - nodes
      - pods
      - services
      - resourcequotas
      - replicationcontrollers
      - limitranges
      - persistentvolumeclaims
      - persistentvolumes
      - namespaces
      - endpoints
    verbs: ["list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["extensions"]
    resources:
      - daemonsets
      - deployments
      - replicasets
      - ingresses
    verbs: ["list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources:
      - daemonsets
      - deployments
      - replicasets
      - statefulsets
    verbs: ["list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["batch"]
    resources:
      - cronjobs
      - jobs
    verbs: ["list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["autoscaling"]
    resources:
      - horizontalpodautoscalers
    verbs: ["list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["policy"]
    resources:
      - poddisruptionbudgets
    verbs: ["list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["certificates.k8s.io"]
    resources:
      - certificatesigningrequests
    verbs: ["list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["storage.k8s.io"]
    resources:
      - storageclasses
    verbs: ["list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["autoscaling.k8s.io"]
    resources:
      - verticalpodautoscalers
    verbs: ["list", "watch"]

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: grafana-prometheus-scraper
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: grafana-prometheus-scraper
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: grafana-prometheus-scraper
```

You don't have to specify the namespace when you are creating Cluster roles as this applies to the whole cluster. If you want to limit the access to a particular namespace you should use Role and RoleBinding.

There is really good article on Medium regarding [Configuring RBAC For Your Kubernetes Service Accounts](https://medium.com/@lestrrat/configuring-rbac-for-your-kubernetes-service-accounts-c348b64eb242) that I strongly recommend.

Comment: Thank you for this, I believe that the SA object needed a Namespace field and the CRB needed to reference the Namespace wherein the SA existed but those manifests work.

In fact, they are 1:1 what I was doing before I migrated to move to Users instead of SAs. The reason I migrated, is that after deploying these manifests Prometheus is not able to scrape any metadata from the cluster with this scrape_config. Any idea why? https://github.com/zimmertr/Kubernetes-Manifests/blob/master/Grafana/manifests/cm_prometheus_configuration.yml.j2

Comment: You can see on this line that the Deployment manifest for Prometheus is configured to use the created Service Account assigned to that Cluster Role. https://github.com/zimmertr/Kubernetes-Manifests/blob/a595c9ed31bcf416b2434d6ffa0ad411c93910fb/Grafana/manifests/dep_prometheus.yml.j2#L23

Perhaps the issue is with the Prometheus configuration?

Comment: Can you post your scrape_config?

Answer (score 0):

There is no user object in kubernetes. create a service account and update the same in clusterrolebinding.

```
subjects:
    - kind: User
      name: grafana-prometheus-scraper
```

Comment: Not disagreeing that a service account might be a better approach but this official documentation says that a User is an object in Kubernetes: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding

Comment: create a service account and check the rbac roles. It should work

Comment: create user using openssl certificate. some users use that way to create users. first you need to check and see if the rbac works fine with service account in your cluster. then map the rolebindings with user, that you created with openssl certs, instead of service account